# Следует ли задавать вопрос в теле вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Не сошлись во мнениях с @Kromster по поводу этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1499135/195342).

Изначально вопрос был сформулирован вкратце в заголовке, затем повторен в теле вопроса, с последующим, я бы сказал, комментарием. Мой визави удалил сам вопрос из тела вопроса, оставив только комментарий. Я вернул вопрос на место, он повторно его выбросил. Словом, смотрите историю правок сами.

Как вы считаете, следует ли задавать вопрос именно в заголовке вопроса?

И не допустимы ли тогда пустые вопросы - без тела?

Comment: На мой взгляд самое главное, чтоб загловок вопроса отражал кратко и как можно более понятно и конкретней суть вопроса. Должен ли сам вопрос содержаться в теле вопроса зависит от размера самого вопроса, его пояснений, комментариев и т.д. В конкретном приведённом Вами примере это не критично, т.к. там всего пару предложений и потеряться/запутаться крайне сложно, но в больших вопросах, на мой взгляд, вопрос должен быть в теле вопроса, чтоб при его чтении не возникала неопределённость о чём спрашивает автор.

Comment: Эти заголовки несут разные смыслы. При "Почему..." ожидается, что будет о том, почему используется то, а не это. А при "Применение..." ожидается, что будут объяснения как применять то, другое и третье. Ну типа "Почему для супа используется столовая ложка, а не чайная" и "Применение столовых и чайных ложек за обедом". Совсем разные темы.

Comment: Пустые вопросы не поощряются движком площадки, потому как качество вопроса коррелирует с его описанием. В приведенном вами вопросе, например, сильно не хватает контекста - с чего вообще ТС взял что что-то используется чаще чем что-то иное, в какой области, итп. С т.з. ruSO, разумнее добавить эти детали и конкретизировать вопрос, чем превращать его в общее аморфное "Об О", ответ на которое потянет на 12 страниц )

Comment: Ответ "об O" *с точки зрения базы знаний* полезнее :) С точки зрения "решить ДЗ здесь и сейчас" — конечно, полезнее вопрос конкретнее, а ответ — просто готовый код...

Comment: "Об О" полезнее для учебника или курсовой об О. Для *Базы Знаний* такие вопросы считаются слишком общими и неконкретными. Целеполагание SO скорее именно про прикладные задачи. Пример с домашками не совсем в тему, т.к. они-то как раз неконкретны донельзя - "Как мне решить домашку?" - "Надо учиться, не прогуливать, делать все в срок, обсуждать с преподами и одноклассниками" итп итд. Если же вопрос по домашке конкретен - то это и есть то, к чему весь Тур по SO ведет.

Comment: С точки зрения SEO, дубликат вопроса в теле повысит шансы поиска в поисковике. Если вопрос задан  в заголовке, а в теле этот вопрос озвучен и развернут это лучше, чем просто заголовок.

Answer (score 6):

У вас не согласован заголовок вопроса и вопрос в теле. Это такой специальный прием-демонстрация? Отвечая буквально - **да, вопрос стоит задавать и в заголовке и в теле, и это должен быть один и тот же вопрос, просто с разным уровнем детализации.**

---

Отвечая на дух вопроса:

Мы с вами на ruSO - сайте вопросов и ответов (См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour). Здесь не место пространным темам "Применение АБС в современном мире", здесь место конкретике "Как сделать АБС в контейнере Докера?".

Вопрос в заголовке стоит задавать потому, что заголовок это краткая выжимка сути "тела вопроса". Если есть конкретная проблема и вопрос по ней, как ни странно, её краткая выжимка - это тоже вопрос.

И наоборот, если не получается сформулировать вопрос для заголовка - это признак неконкретного вопроса или отсутствующих деталей проблемы (типа, "сделайте за меня", "я и мое задание", "RecursionError pyinstaller", "Новая ошибка в дискорд боте", "Кнопки disnake "ctx", итд..).

Также, стоит стараться избегать излишних обобщений. Если вопрос достаточно короток чтобы быть заголовком ("Как вставить элементы в QGridLayout чтобы они не наползали друг на друга?"), не надо его размывать и превращать в аморфное "Особенности QGridLayout" - теперь без открытия вопроса не понять о чем он.